# Absolute paths in CakePHP project

Tags: php, cakephp

i was given a pretty big cakePHP (built on v. `1.3.10`) project to maintain. The problem is that the majority of the paths are absolute (which on my opinion is a bad habit).

Eg. in default.ctp there is:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/public_new.css" />`

but then at the bottom of the same file there is:

`<?php echo $html->script('jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js'); ?>`

which prints the correct paths.

It's like the original developers made the site to put in a server's root (not in a subdirectory).

Things ive tried to solve this problem without success:

- modified the .htaccess files on /, app/, and app/webroot
- adding a  tag

I know i can add a `$this->base` to the beginning of every path, but this is not a solution since there are thousands of files to modifiy :(

So my question: is there any solution using mod_rewrite or such?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although it's better practice to use the built-in HtmlHelper, using a 'base path' of `/css/something.css` shouldn't be a big obstacle, as it will point to the webroot/ of the app, not the "server's root".

Unless you plan on moving the `css` folder outside of the `webroot/`, it should work fine without modifying anything.

Comment: As Dave mentioned, using the HtmlHelper is the best approach. Just wanted to add a comment regarding 'bad habit'; When using CakePHP it *is* best to use absolute paths. Relative paths will lead you into problems, because the browser will try to locate the CSS *relative to the current path*. For example; when using `css/main.css`, the browser will try to find the stylesheet in `/mycontroller/myaction/1234/css/main.css`, which obviously results in a 404

Comment: What I mean by good practice is that paths shouldn't be hard coded, but instead be in the form of Router::url('/path/to/file')

Answer (score 0):

`$html->script()` will automatically prepend `/js/` in the HTML output. Cake's .htaccess will then point these file calls to `/webroot/js/`.

So `<?php echo $html->script('jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js'); ?>` would output

`/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js` in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To replace all those urls / links you could actually use a program like Actual Search and Replace ;-) I use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

on app/config/boostrap.php, add:

`Configure::write('App.base', '/teka_new/');`

I take this out from [Ho do I change the base path of routes in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719486/ho-do-i-change-the-base-path-of-routes-in-cakephp)